# C++ UDP socket corrupts packet over a certain frequency

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, udp

I am developing a simple file transfer protocol based on UDP.
To make sure that packets are sent correctly, I am checksumming them. At the moment of receiving, corrupt packets are dropped. I begun by testing my protocol at home within my home network. I have seen it support several MB/s upload bandwidth to the internet so I expected it to perform nicely with two computers connected to the same wifi router.

What happened is that when I reach up to 10000 packets per second (packets are of a few bytes only!) packets start appearing massively (about 40% to 60%) corrupt (checksum fails). What could be the cause of this problem? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: how big is each packet? What wireless mode is your router running in? How strong is the signal?

Comment: UDP already has a checksumming facility. You should enable that at both ends. You don't need to implement this yourself.

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding the tools you're using for debugging and some sort of output related to the problem? We don't know at this moment if the packet is being discarded at kernel level because of a checksum mismatch (somewhere in the stack.. is it IP checksum? UDP checksum?), or if it's your own checksum implementation output that's flagging the packet as corrupt.

Comment: I also suggest you to test your code through a loopback interface.

Comment: Each packet is up to maybe 20 bytes. Wireless protocol N, full signal strength. I am using a bucket checksum technique to make my protocol slimmer, therefore I need to implement checksum myself. I have a code in C++ that outputs something when a checksum goes bad. Through a loopback interface everything works nicely.

Comment: Does Wireshark agree that incoming packets are being corrupted?  It seems to me that if your app works on a wired LAN at higher data rates, then your access point is probably awful and corrupting packets.  Also, you should consider much, much larger payloads.  You have at least `14+20+8=42` bytes of header per packet, so roughly 2/3 of your bandwidth is wasted, resulting in tremendously low packets per second (PPS).

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a connectionless oriented protocol - meaning, you can send UDP packets at any time - if someone is listening they'll get the packet.  If they don't, they don't.  Packets are **NOT** guaranteed to arrive.

You cannot send UDP packets the same way you are doing with TCP.   You have to handle each packet as its own.  For example, with socket/TCP, you can write as much data as you want and TCP will get it over there unless you overflow the socket itself.  It's reliable.

UDP is not.   If you send UDP packet and it gets lost, it's lost forever and there no way to recover it - you'll have to do the recovery yourself in your own protocol above the layer.  There is no resend, it's not a reliable connection.

Although there is a checksum, it's typically optional and typically not used.

UDP is great for streaming data, such as music, voice, etc.   There are recovery protocols such as RTP above the UDP layer for voice that can recover data in the voice coders themselves.

I bet if you put a counter in the UDP packet, you'll note that some of them does not arrive if you exceed a certain bandwith and definitely will run into this if you are connecting it through a switch/network.  If you do a direct connection between two computers, it may work at a very high bandwidth though.